# Events not working in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, f#

So I decided to try the F# Empty Windows App (WPF) template [link here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e0907c99-bb04-4eb8-9692-9333d5ff4399). It has this kind of boilerplate code template.

```ml
module MainApp

open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls
open FSharpx

type MainWindow = XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">

let loadWindow() =
   let window = MainWindow()  
   let x = new TestWindow1.Test1()
   x.Root.Show();
   window.Root

[<STAThread>]
(new Application()).Run(loadWindow()) |> ignore
```

It seemed to load the window just fine so I assumed it was a correct way to load XAML using F#. I put in the TestWindow1.Test1 obviously.

So when I got to my own class (TestWindow1.Test) I ran into a problem. All of the click events I set up in the loadwindow() method did not work.

It's nothing fancy since its a test, but it doesn't work and I am not sure what is wrong or how to fix it since everything compiles, and there are no exceptions in Debug mode.

```ml
module TestWindow1
//open statements here
type Test1 = XAML<"Test1.xaml">
let LoadWindow() =
    let window = Test1()


    window.TextBOX.TextChanged.Add(
     fun _ -> window.textBlock.Text <- window.TextBox.Text)

    window.changecolorbtn.Click.Add(
     fun _->  let mutable x = window.textblock.Foreground :?> SolidColorBrush //down cast the brush to a solid color brush
                 if x = Brushes.Red then x <- Brushes.Black
                 else x <- Brushes.Red
                 )


    window.Root
```

I am just not sure why it doesn't do anything. Anyway, I would be glad to post the XAML for Test1 if it helps.

### **Update**

I tried to put the  [ < STAThread > ] above the loadWindow() block like so according to ethicallogics's answer, it still does not work.

```ml
  type MainWindow = XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">
[<STAThread>]
let loadWindow() =
   let window = MainWindow()
   let x = new TestWindow1.Test1()
   x.Root.Show();
   window.Root

[<STAThread>]
(new Application()).Run(loadWindow()) |> ignore
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen in the event handlers?

Comment: So there is a textbox and a textblock in the first one. I expect that the text of the textblock is replaced with what is in the textbox when the contents are changed.  For the other one, it should switch the background color of the textblock between red or black when changecolorbtn is clicked.

Comment: I think that you're trying to invoke wrong function. You might need to invoke `Run(TestWindow1.LoadWindow())`, instead of `Run(loadWindow())`.

Answer (score 4):

Put `[<STAThread>]` above

```ml
let loadWindow() =
let window = MainWindow()  
let x = new TestWindow1.Test1()
x.Root.Show();
window.Root
```

like

```ml
[<STAThread>]
let loadWindow() =
let window = MainWindow()  
let x = new TestWindow1.Test1()
x.Root.Show();
window.Root
```

Answer (score 1):

For the textbox, it might be `TextBOX` vs. `TextBox`.

For the color: you are assigning the color to the local variable `x`, try setting `window.textblock.Foreground <- ...`, `window.Textblock.Foreground <- ...` or even `window.textBlock.Foreground` (typo here as well?)

If your code really compiles, I'd double check the XAML for components having a name that differs only by casing.